# py4j.Py4JException: Method socketTextStream does not exist

Tags: pycharm, pyspark, py4j

I am new to Spark Streaming. Using PySpark in PyCharm I am unable to get passed the socketTextStream initialization.

```
def start_streaming (self):
    sp = SparkContext('local[2]', 'streamingTest')
    stream = StreamingContext(sp, 1)
    **items = stream.socketTextStream('localhost', '9009')**
    print(items)
    lines = items.flatMap(lambda line : line.split('\n'))
```

I am receiving the following error. Any ideas on what the problem is?

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "/Users/egorkorneev/PycharmProjects/BasicStreaming/SparkConsumer.py",
>   line 75, in  dc.start_streaming()  File
>   "/Users/egorkorneev/PycharmProjects/BasicStreaming/SparkConsumer.py",
>   line 40, in start_streaming items =
>   stream.socketTextStream('localhost', '9009')  File
>   "/Users/egorkorneev/rnd/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py",
>   line 352, in socketTextStream return
>   DStream(self._jssc.socketTextStream(hostname, port, jlevel), self, 
>   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 933, in **call** answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id,
>   self.name)  File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 316, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name, value))
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling
>   o19.socketTextStream. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method
>   socketTextStream([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String,
>   class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel]) does not exist at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
>   at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
>   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252) at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Spark 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

The port number should be an integer value.

items = stream.socketTextStream('localhost', 9009)